# How to add indicators, signals and rules to previous period data quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat

I am a newbie and trying to create my own bactesting code after going through demo(). I am using a candle engulfing pattern strategy and this is the formula

```
buy=(close(1) < close) and (high(1) < high) and (low(1) < low) 
sell=(close(1) > close) and (high(1) > high) and (low(1) > low) 
*(1) represents previous day data
```

How should i get previous day data for close,high and open for the previous day? 
How should i add indicators,rules and signals to this strategy.

So far i am able to code this much but got stuck at adding indicators, rules and signals

```
require(quantstrat)
ttz<-Sys.getenv('TZ')
Sys.setenv(TZ='UTC')

stock.str='AAPL' 
currency('USD')
stock(stock.str,currency='USD',multiplier=1)
  initDate="2013-12-31"
  endDate=Sys.Date()
  portfolio.st='engulf'
account.st='engulf'
initPortf(portfolio.st,symbols=stock.str, initDate=initDate)
initAcct(account.st,portfolios=portfolio.st, initDate=initDate,initEq=initEq)
initOrders(portfolio=portfolio.st,initDate=initDate)

stratENGULF<- strategy(portfolio.st)

#previous day data
n<-nrow(mktdata)
predata<-mktdata[n-1,]

#add indictors,rule and signal
stratENGULF <- add.indicator("Dont_know_what_to_add" )
stratENGULF <- add.signal("Dont_know_what_to_add" )
stratENGULF <- add.rule("Dont_know_what_to_add" )
#Cl(mktdata),Hi(mktdata) and Lo(mktdata) for getting current close,high and low price
```

I was able to retrieve previous day data using this code

```
#previous day data
n<-nrow(mktdata)
predata<-mktdata[n-1,]
```

But dont know how to add `predata's close` and compare with close of `mktdata`in indicator and signal.

Any idea for solving this problem

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Getting-previous-day-data-and-implementing-it-for-quantstrat-td4710978.html). At minimum, tell people that you're cross-posting, so they don't spend time answering a question that was answered on another forum they do not follow.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Deleted the question from that forum. Sorry for cross posting

Comment: You can't delete it. It's a mailing list. Nabble simply slaps a web-UI on it.